# Connecting Subversion Repo with Maven

Tags: svn, maven-2

I created a maven project in eclipse. I uploaded it to my subversion server. Now on my testing server I installed maven and I want to connect it with my svn repository to run test builds on. Not sure how to do this since I have only worked with Maven via the eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now on my testing server I installed maven and I want to connect it with my svn repository to run test builds on.

Not sure what do you mean by "connect" exactly. Anyway, whatever the expected result is, if you want to checkout a project from subversion, you'll need a subversion client on this machine.

Then, you can either checkout  the project using a regular [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re04.html) command as suggested by @krosenvold.

```
svn checkout URL... [PATH]
```

Or you could use Maven and the [Maven SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) and its [`scm:checkout`](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html) mojo (but `svn` still need to be on the path i.e. you still need the subversion client to be installed). For example:

```
mvn scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:https://svn.dev.java.net/svn/hudson/trunk/hudson -DcheckoutDirectory=hudson
```

In my opinion, there is no real advantage at using the later (actually, it's the contrary: the command is more verbose, you need to use maven scm url format). I would just use a regular **`svn checkout`**.

Note that getting sources from the repository (at regular interval or upon changes), running the build (compiling sources, tests, running tests, QA checks, generating reports, etc), notifying upon failure is usually done by a continuous integration engine. Maybe have a look at [**Hudson**](http://hudson-ci.org/) if you are interested.

Comment: ok this is more what I was thinking....however your advice is to not use it and simply check out the repo with svn

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to install eclipse on the testing server you will probably need to install a subversion client and do a checkout with the client.

```
 svn co <url to repository>
```

Then you can probably just build with

```
mvn install
```

Or whatever maven command you normally use

Comment: this is what I will use. I accepted the other answer because it explained the maven scm plug-in and why not to use it. Thanks for your answer though.